# What kind of chilli is this that grows upwards?

Tags: identification, chili

This is a chilli I grew from some left over seeds. It's chillies grow upright. It's flowers are white on the inside and have purple lines on the outside.

Any idea what kind of chilli it is?

[image: chilli plant]

Update: The chillies have now turned bright red (after briefly turning wine colour)

[image: ripening]

Answer (score 1):

Most but not all chilies that grow upright are of the species *[Capsicum frutescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_frutescens)*. There are many, many cultivars. When they begin to ripen, watch for color changes. This may help narrow it down a bit. Could be birdseye, tabasco, etc. [Have a look here](https://www.pepperscale.com/ornamental-peppers/) for many upright growing chilies that are considered 'ornamental'.

Comment: OK, will wait a few more weeks to see what colour they turn. The seeds they came from were from a red round chilli if I recall correctly (seeds were around 2 years old). But I could be wrong, because I also had another chilli which was orange but it was of the long type so I assumed it wouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: They first turned dark red, almost wine colour for a few days then turned bright red. Picture added.

Comment: I don't think they are either birdseye (the shape doesn't look like it) nor tabasco (according to online sources from green it first turns yellow, then orange, then red. In my case it first turned wine colour, then bright red.